# Oracle CBO when using types

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an interesting issue with the CBO on Oracle 11g R2 that I cant seem to work out. Assume the following (note that this is cut down DDL for brevity);

```
create or replace object o_primary_key ( id number(38,0) );
create or replace type t_primary_key table of o_primary_key;

create table customer (
  customer_id number(38, 0) primary key,
  parent_customer_id number(38, 0),
  ... additional columns ommitted ...
)

create table orders (
  order_id number(38, 0) not null primary key,
  customer_id number(38, 0) not null,
  date_applied date not null,
  deleted_on date null,
  amount number(18, 9) not null,
  ... additional columns ommitted ...
)

index idx_orders_1 on orders (customer_id, date_applied, deleted_on, order_id);

index idx_customers_1 on customer (parent_customer_id, case when parent_customer_id is not null then customer_id else null end) compute statistics;
```

The CUSTOMERS table has about 200,000 rows and the ORDERS table has about 6 million rows. I have a query such as the following and the intent of this query
is to display all the orders for the given customer id or if the customer id is a parent then all of the orders for its children.

```
with c_ids as (
  select 1 as id from dual union all
  select 2 as id from dual union all
  select 3 as id from dual
),
c_customer_ids as (
  select t.id customer_id,
         c.parent_customer_id joining_customer_id
  from   c_ids t
  join   customers c
  on     t.id = c.customer_id
  or     t.id = c.parent_customer_id
)
select   *
from     c_customer_ids
join     orders o
on       o.customer_id = c.joining_customer_id
where    o.date_applied bewteen '10/MAY/15' and '13/MAY/15'
and      o.deleted_on is null
order by o.customer_id,
         o.date_applied;
```

when I run this query, the CBO correctly (I beleive) decides to rewrite the OR portion of the query using the CONCATENATION operation such that it runs in part against the CUSTOMER_ID's and 
then against the PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID's as a second run. Both of these use queries use the index and the number of consistent gets is very low (around 200).

Note that in the case I am testing I am pulling out about
1,800 rows from the total of 6 million.

However, it gets interesting when I run the query such as this;

```
with c_customer_ids as (
  select t.id customer_id,
         c.parent_customer_id joining_customer_id
  from   table(t_primary_key(o_primary_key(1), o_primary_key(2), o_primary_key(3))) t
  join   customers c
  on     t.id = c.customer_id
  or     t.id = c.parent_customer_id
)
select   *
from     c_customer_ids
join     orders o
on       o.customer_id = c.joining_customer_id
where    o.date_applied bewteen '10/MAY/15' and '13/MAY/15'
and      o.deleted_on is null
order by o.customer_id,
         o.date_applied;
```

When using the types to define the numbers the CBO decides to incorrectly (I believe) run it as a single query using a full table scan on the ORDERS table and therefore the consisent gets is around 130,000 and
the query runs alot slower.

Why does the use of the type's cause such a difference?

Thanks,
Cain

Comment: What happens if you add the `CARDINALITY` hint to your second query? `select /*+ CARDINALITY( t 3 ) */ t.id customer_id`

Comment: Adding the CARDINALITY hint forces the query to be split and a CONCATENATION is used, however, the part that runs the check for the parents is still performing a full table scan so this actually makes it slower even still.

Comment: This is perhaps a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20892914/409172), even though the queries look completely different.  The short version is: Oracle makes a wild guess at the cardinality of anything that could have procedural code.  Estimating 8168 rows instead of 3 can radically alter the execution plan.  The `CARDINALITY` hint may help, as Peter suggested, although it can be tricky to get right.  I find that the `DYNAMIC_SAMPLING` hint usually works well in these cases.

Comment: great, the DYNAMIC_SAMPLING did the trick!